# need help to make client-server app in eclipse

Tags: android, client

1. I need a client server example and steps to create it on eclipse,

   1. I am using eclipse and i have tomcat7.0 and wamp server in my PC,
   2. I have a device (samsung mobile) that i want to use as server/client and emulator(AVD) as client / server,
   3. How to create a server side app in eclipse? please explain with all steps,
   4. How test / run app?

Answer (score 0):

How are the client and the server going to communicate? Through Wifi/Bluetooth/Using http?The only true client server model that comes in to my mind is having let's say php pages that you are going to send HttpRequests (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android) for an example) from your android application and the server will handle. In the case of bluetooth wifi you just have to open a socket and send the data. It must be noted that your pc and the emulator have different ip address range, thus in case of TCP/IP socket it is quite tricky (although I think it is possible) to establish a communication between your android phone and an Android virtual device. I hope I didn't misunderstood anything.